# 2 SetTimeOut Method inside Promise not working

Tags: javascript

Couldn't find a solution for the same hence reaching out to you guys for help.

I have 2 JS method that needs to be called a specific time interval continuously so to achieve this i used SetTimeout as shown below but it does not seem to work and only second setTimeout is called . Ideally i expected that both methods would be called after the mentioned time.

My code:-

```
var statusPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        plugin.dcsHelper.getMeterStatus(function(data) {
            plugin.dcsHelper.log("INFO", "Status: " + JSON.stringify(data));
            if (data && data.status) {
                resolve(data.status);
            }
        }, function(err) {
            plugin.dcsHelper.log("ERROR", "Error while polling: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    }, 1000);
});

var progressPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        plugin.dcsHelper.getProgress2(function(data) {
            plugin.dcsHelper.log("INFO", "Value: " + JSON.stringify(data));
            if (data && data.val) {
                resolve(data.val);
            }
        }, function(err) {
            plugin.dcsHelper.log("ERROR", "Error while polling: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    }, 5000);
});

Promise.all([statusPromise, progressPromise]).then(function(values) {
    console.log(values);
});
```

Here the method inside progressPromise is only getting called and the method inside statusPromise is not getting called.

Any help will be much appreciated.!!

Comment: What's your actual result ? Did you try to add console.log inside the setTimeout of statusPromise to check if it's called

Comment: Expected was both method getting called at mentioned time interval but, what is happening is getProgress is only called.

Comment: Are you sure that `data` and `data.val` inside `progressPromise` are truthy? Have you tried logging them inside the console?

Comment: Put a `console.log` before calling `setTimeout`. It should output. Are you sure that `plugin.dcsHelper.getMeterStatus` is calling the callback that is passed to it? Could you test this separately without the promises?

Comment: yes, data and data.val are very much valid as it is logged.  Yup tried without promise as well result is same. Yes callback i double checked they are valid.

Comment: plugin.dcsHelper.log basically logs it in console so yes, data and data.val are getting logged correctly.

Comment: could you post your output Vishesh? With some explanation of the output too...

Comment: below is sample output  Status: {"IN_PROGRESS"} then Value:{"1.0"} again Value:{"2.0"} again continuously Value output is printed and Status is not printed

Answer (score 0):

Actually the above code is completely right and promise works as expected . The problem was with the Plugin java code which i was using.